# Is there a way I can create a custom erpnext app without being prompted for the inputs,eg;description, etc... while using the "bench new-app" command?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, erpnext, frappe

I want to create an app using a bash script inside my docker-compose.yml file but the problem is I am being prompted for the app details like the App Title,description etc which are usually there by default.This leads to the process getting aborted hence the app doesn't get created.

I have tried various options such as "bench new-app [app_name] --no-options",
"bench new-app [app_name] --no-description",....which are obviously invalid

Comment: I don't know `bench`, but how does it read the response to the prompts? Depending on the exact details, you could perhaps redirect stdin to a response file, or use something like [expect](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Expect+Examples), if you need more control over how to drive `bench`? .

Comment: When I used "expect" , I got an error indicating "expect command not found".This is inside the docker container.When I try to install it,I get an error "sudo: command not found".Is there a way I can install these commands inside my docker container without using "sudo"?

Comment: If I get _command not found_, the first  I try to use the absolute path for the command. Aside from this, I don't know enough about docker help you with the installation, but since you now have a new problem, i.e. "how to install _expect_ in a docker container?_, I suggest that you post this as a new question. But ask here on StackOverflow (where it likely will be closed), ask instead on [su], which is the appropriate place for discussing installation problems.